# Create a 100 number vector with random values in R rounded to 2 decimals

Tags: r

I need to do a pretty simple task,but since im not versed in R I don't know exactly how to. I have to create a vector of 100 numbers with random values from 0 to 1 with 2 DECIMAL numbers. I've tried this:

```
 x2 <- runif(100, 0.0, 1.0)
```

and it works great, but the numbers have 8 decimal numbers and I need them with only 2.

Comment: Do you really need numbers with 2dp, or only need them _displayed_ with 2 dp? If it's the latter, `sprintf("%.2f", x2)`

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps also:

```
(sample.int(101,size=100,replace=TRUE)-1)/100
```

Answer (score 9):

So you want to sample numbers randomly from the set { 0, 1/100, 2/100, ..., 1 }? Then write exactly that in code:

```
hundredths <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)
sample(hundredths, size=100, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Keeping it simple!  Very nice.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps

```
x1 = round(runif(100,0,1), 2)
```

- `100`: Number of random numbers
- `0`: Min value
- `1`: max value
- `2`: rounded to two decimal palaces

Answer (score 5):

Or

```
x2 <- round( runif(100, -0.005, 1.0049, 2 )
```

Comment: You cannot see Paul's deleted answer... This is not correct because the end points (`0.00` and `1.00`) will have half the probability of all other points.

Comment: @flodel -you are right, thanks. I was just modifiying the OP's approach, but probably he himself didn't think of it. Edited so that the probabilities should now be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix: 
x2 <- round(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0), digits=2)

Will round to two DP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round` over `runif` to generate random numbers.

> Vector = round(runif(number of random numbers, min value, max value),
> decimal places)

Eg: `Vector = round(runif(10,0,1),3)` //it generate 10 random numbers with 3 decimal places